# Kinect point cloud to pcd files

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, pcd, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using the openni_launch stack to gather data from the kinect sensor. I'm currently able to visualize the points cloud with rviz. I need to save each incoming frame as a .pcd file for data processing, is there a easy way to do so with ROS?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47345/kinect-point-cloud-to-pcd-files/) by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use pointcloud_to_pcd stated in [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd).

You're able to visualize the points cloud with rviz, so I assumed that you know which topic is transmitting the pointcloud you need.

You can store the pointcloud to a pcd file by simply running

```
rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=<your target topic name>
```

If the data in "your target topic name" is valid pointcloud data, this executable will automatically save the pointcloud to a pcd file.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2012-11-05**:
Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need!

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-06**:
Welcome: )

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-05-20**:
Will this still work with ROS Hydro?

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2014-07-02**:
I am not sure~You can give it a try: )

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-04-07**:
I did that but the cloud is saved upside down because orientation in rviz how can i fix this